# Multiple table view controller in universal Device using Objective-C

Tags: ios, uitableview, master-detail, ios-universal-app

I need to build a project which has multiple table view controller and detail view controller in Objective-C using the Universal Device ...

I am not able to find any good tutorial or any tips on the topic

Please do help me to find the tutorial or solutions...

Answer (score 0):

No matter, how many tables you have,just create UITableViewControler and call where and when you need. but you need to configure only how many different cell you are for each table view.

And Call each table view when you need.

You can see apple provided default example template "Master-Detail Application"

Comment: the problem is not multiple view but that of the split view that appear only in first  table view rest of the table view show nonsplit table view now how to convet this...plz help

Comment: can send code sample where the specific problem you fell

Comment: the problem is i am not able to implement  the split view controller in universal device ...i try with normal table view controller it work but it does not give the split view i needed